# How to update the column to add auto increment using a MAX value from column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    COLUMN1 INT,
    COLUMN2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
  (
    COLUMN1,
    COLUMN2
  )
VALUES
  (1, 5),
  (2, 4),
  (3, NULL),
  (4, 2),
  (5, NULL)
```

I want to update the `COLUMN2` to add auto increment using a MAX value from a column.

I tried this query:

```
DECLARE @maxNumber        INT = 0;
SELECT @maxNumber = ISNULL(MAX(COLUMN2), 0) + 1
FROM   #TempTable

SELECT @maxNumber

CREATE SEQUENCE [tempSqu] AS [int] START 
WITH @maxNumber INCREMENT BY 1

UPDATE #TempTable
SET    COLUMN2 = NEXT VALUE FOR [tempSqu]
WHERE  COLUMN2 IS NULL

DROP sequence [tempSqu]
```

The output:

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2
--------------------
1           5
2           4
3           6
4           2
5           7
```

Comment: Can you include the expected output after update in your question so it will become more clear?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Using `MAX+1` always ends up producing duplicate values if the latest entries are deleted or changed. You don't need a SEQUENCE to produce incrementing values either, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` or any other ranking function to produces a rank number for each row

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE tmp
SET tmp.COLUMN2 = @maxNumber, @maxNumber = @maxNumber + 1
FROM #TempTable tmp
WHERE tmp.COLUMN2 IS NULL
```

Comment: This is the simplest and the shortest answer as per the current requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with dynamic SQL something like this:

```
DECLARE @maxNumber INT = 0
    ,@sequenceDSQL VARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @maxNumber = ISNULL(MAX(COLUMN2), 0) + 1
FROM #TempTable

SET @sequenceDSQL = 'CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[tempSqu] AS [int] START WITH '
    + CAST(@maxNumber AS VARCHAR(19)) +
    'INCREMENT BY 1 UPDATE #TempTable
    SET COLUMN2 = NEXT VALUE FOR [tempSqu]
    WHERE COLUMN2 IS NULL
    DROP sequence [tempSqu]'

EXEC (@sequenceDSQL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with `Row_Number()` function and `inner join update` as shown below.

Note: I have provided the logic in the comment with the query.

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable
(
    COLUMN1     INT,
    COLUMN2     INT
)

INSERT INTO TempTable ( COLUMN1, COLUMN2 )
VALUES (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, NULL), (4, 2), (5, NULL), (6, 9), (7, NULL), (8, NULL)

--Getting the maximum value available in the table.
declare @maxValue int = (Select top 1 Column2 from TempTable 
          where Column2 is not null order by column2 desc)

Update 
     t set t.column2 = @maxValue + SrNo --Update with max value with SrNo as sequence 
from TempTable t inner join (
  SELECT COLUMN1
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) AS SRNO --It will always give value in sequence like 1, 2, 3, ...
    FROM TempTable where COLUMN2 is null
)temp on t.Column1 = temp.Column1 
where t.column2 is null

--Selecting the record after update
Select * from TempTable order by column1
```

Here is the [live db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3fcd11b7844ec8e4d1282ffade5aed8).

[image]